# htaccess rewrite only if file doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using .htaccess mod rewrite, I would like to rewrite a url, check if that file exists, and if not rewrite again to another url using part of the original url which was removed during the 1st re-write.

For example, if the original url is this

/images/3001/zebra.jpg

I would like to check if the file exists /images/cached/zebra.jpg  and serve it if it does exist.

And if not I would like to rewrite to /image.php?id=3001

Thanks very much,
Phil

Comment: I don't think that `mod_rewrite` is capable of this. Your `image.php` script should do the checking for you. If it exists, it should serve the cached version, otherwise it should serve the original and cache it. Then, create the rewrite for that script if you'd like to *fake* the URI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently my php script does check as you described, but it means invoking php to process the request. I was hoping it would be more efficient for the server to skip php if possible.

Answer (score 3):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add these rules before whatever rules you may already have there:

```
RewriteEngine On

# cached copy exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/[0-9]+/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/cached/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ /images/cached/%1 [L]

# cached copy doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/([0-9]+)/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/cached/%2 !-f
RewriteRule ^ /image.php?id=%1 [L]
```