# HTTP: Redirection to one of several pages

Tags: javascript, html, http, redirect, relative-path

I wonder is it even possible: I'd like to redirect my 404 page to . [current catalog], or to .. [level up] if the first one failed.

The idea is if someone tries to reach http://mypage.asd/cat1/cat2/page.html, and there is no cat2 catalog in cat1 - browser would (eventually) get to cat1.

I don't want different 404 pages for different subcatalogs, which would be easier to make - so here I am with my question.

Page is in html with js elements. Tried dynamically changing meta tags with js, but it doesn't work (js is executed onload, meta tags are parsed earlier) and looks awful.

My redirection code - for now - is standard:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3 URL=./">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this on the server side -- intercept the raw http request, and then if the page doesn't exist, load a different page based on arbitrary logic. Depending on what server side platform/framework you're using, this could be achieved in various ways.

You could possible do this using .htaccess if you're running Apache server. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182769/htaccess-rewrite-only-if-file-doesnt-exist) for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just comment that @anand.trex 's reply is THE answer for such a use case. When redirecting, especially with invalid URLs, for a multitude of reasons it is better to use server-side redirection, like through .htaccess of Apache's server.